# GPU crashes when running Keras/tensorflow-gpu, specifically when clock speed goes to idle at 0 MHz

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run Keras with a Tensorflow GPU backend. I've done some testing with various dummy models while simultaneously monitoring my GPU usage using MSI Afterburner, GPU-Z, nvidia-smi and Task Manager. My GPU is a GeForce GTX 960M, which has no issues running games. The temperatures are also low when running Keras.

What I've noticed is that the Keras runs fine (e.g. loading or training a model) in the beginning but whenever Keras is not running anything, the GPU naturally wants to idle from 1097 MHz to 0 MHz and as soon as it does that the GPU crashes. I can see that the "GPU is lost" on NVSMI. I have to then disable and re-enable my GPU in the Device Manager to get it to work.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Edit: I can temporarily prevent this from happening for very small programs by using the "allow_growth" feature as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)
```

However, this only works if the operation is really small such that it uses only about 0.1 GB of GPU memory such as loading a model or running a really small model. However, if the program is using memory of even 0.3 GB of memory my GPU crashes since the memory does not go to 0 GB *before* the clock speed drops to 0 MHz (lower power state).

Comment: Your laptop probably has a built-in Intel graphics adapter along with the NVidia.  I'm guessing Windows is disabling / switching you to the Intel mistakenly when it sees little activity.  You might try going into the NVidia control panel and telling it to always run your app under the 960M.

Comment: @bivouac0 I tried setting the "python.exe" file for my environment to run only on dedicated GPU through the NVIDIA control panel and my GPU still dies.

Comment: You might try disabling the on-board GPU in the bios (if there's an option) or uninstalling the Intel drivers in Device Manager.  There's also the "high performance state" for all programs you could try.  Those might not be the right long-term solution but they would tell you if the issue is Windows switching GPUs.

Comment: @bivouac0 I tried disabling the Intel drivers and that didn't work. How do I try the high performance state?

Comment: In the NVidia control panel, the first tab is for "all" programs.  The drop-down is probably set to "auto" but you can set it to NVidia/high-performance.  In any event, there should be a way to set your laptop to use only the NVidia.  I haven't done this myself but you should be able to Google for it.

Comment: @bivouac0 Oh right, I had already tried that with no luck.

Comment: @bivouac0 Finally figured out that it was a driver issue. I've posted the details in the solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out the issue thanks to someone from another forum. It was a driver issue. The latest drivers provided by Nvidia are causing the issue unlike the old drivers provided by my laptop manufacturer.

Since I was not able to run tensorflow with my old drivers and do more troubleshooting, what I did was download eDrawings Viewer and open up some random assembly drawings I found online. First I tried with the latest Nvidia drivers, and I see that when I manipulate the models, my card is at P0 state but if I don't do anything and let the software idle, my card goes to a lower power state and crashes my GPU. But when I did the same exercise with my ASUS manufacturer-certified drivers (since this software was compatible even with the older drivers unlike TF), my GPU did NOT crash.

What I also discovered was that eDrawings Viewer does not crash even with the latest Nvidia drivers if I go into the Nvidia Control Panel and select "Prefer Maximum Performance" under Power Management Mode. The card stays at P0 state whenever I have the software open even after idling for minutes. Unfortunately, since python.exe does not have a graphical interface, this option does not work for my case. As a workaround, I can still run tensorflow without getting it to crash by running eDrawings Viewer in the background (or really any program that uses a graphical interface), which keeps my card at the P0 State.